# Evaluation Of Iterated Limit

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f: \textrm{dom}(f) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Let $a \in \textrm{dom}(f)$.

Assume $f''(a)$ exists.

Want To Prove $f''(a) = \displaystyle\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a + h) + f(a - h) - 2f(a)}{h^2}$ .

$f''(a)$

$= \displaystyle\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f'(a + h) - f'(a)}{h}$

$= \displaystyle\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\displaystyle\lim_{k \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a + h + k) - f(a + h)}{k} - \lim_{k \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a + k) - f(a)}{k}}{h}$

$= \displaystyle\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\displaystyle\lim_{k \rightarrow 0} \bigg( \frac{f(a + h + k) - f(a + h)}{k} - \frac{f(a + k) - f(a)}{k} \bigg)}{h}$

$= \displaystyle\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\displaystyle\lim_{k \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a + h + k) - f(a + h) - f(a + k) + f(a)}{k}}{h}$

$= \displaystyle\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \Bigg( \! \lim_{k \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(a + h + k) - f(a + h) - f(a + k) + f(a)}{hk} \Bigg)$

In order to get the desired result, I would like to replace $k$ with $-h$. I did this because as $h \rightarrow 0$ and $k \rightarrow 0$, $k \rightarrow -h$.

However, this reasoning of "$h \rightarrow 0$ and $k \rightarrow 0$" would be more applicable in the case of a two-variable limit as $(h, k) \rightarrow (0, 0)$ rather than an iterated limit as seen in the expression, which may not be equal: [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit#Counterexamples) .

So how can I justify replacing $k$ with $-h$?

I thought about using the Moore-Osgood Theorem, which says the iterated limit is equal to the two-variable limit under a sufficient condition. However, I am unfamiliar with multivariable calculus and I am not sure how I would use it in this case. Unfortunately, I also cannot find a proof that follows Wikipedia's description: [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit#Sufficient_condition) .

Comment: You cannot simply let $k=-h$.  Note that $h$ is held fixed while $k\to 0$.

Comment: @MarkViola but can I let h = -k ?

Comment: No. $k$ is a dummy variable inside the first limit.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Taylor’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem?wprov=sfti1) it exists a map $r_2$ defined in a neighborhood of zero such that

- $f(a+h)=f(a)+f^{\prime}(a)h +\frac{1}{2}f^{\prime\prime}(a)h^2+h^2r_2(h)$
- $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} r_2(h)=0$

You then get the desired conclusion from the equality
$$\frac{f(a + h) + f(a - h) - 2f(a)}{h^2}=f^{\prime\prime}(a)+r_2(h)+r_2(-h)$$

Comment: (+1)  This is the correct approach